# WPF: Create a UserControl or a CustomControl?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, user-controls, custom-controls

I'm not very clear of when to use a CustomControl and when to use an UserControl. I basically know what CustomControl allow(more customization when using with template).

I want to make a "File browse" control in WPF(TextBlock that displays the current path + Button that trigger a "Open File Dialog").

I'm not sure, because at some places I find that they say this should always "replace" a WPF control. I was more thinking that a a CustomControl was more like a way to display and edit **one** new semantic value (in my case, a "File(path)").

So, if we don't take into account which one is easier to do, what would be the more adequate between CustomControl and UserControl for the "FileBrowse" control that I'm speaking about?

Thank you

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Custom Control:**

- A loosely coupled control w.r.t code and UI
- Derives from Control
- Defines UI in a ResourceDictionary
- UI can be changed in different projects
- Has full toolbox support
- Defines a single control
- More flexible

**User Control :**

- A tightly coupled control w.r.t code and UI
- Derives from UserControl
- Defines UI as normal XAML
- UI is fixed and can't have different looks in different project
- Can't be added to the toolbox
- Defines a set of controls
- Not very flexible like a Custom Control

When we talk about differences, it is more important to emphasis on the context **when to use what**:

- When you have a rapid and fixed content in your UI, use UserControl.
- When you want to separate some basic functionality of your main view to some smaller pieces with reusability, use UserControl.
- When you want to use your control in different projects and each project may want to change the look, use CustomControl.
- When you want to implement some additional functionality for a control, create a CustomControl derived from the base control.
- When you want to apply themes to your controls, use CustomControl.
- When you want to add toolbox support for your control, so that your user will be able to do drag and drop to the designer, use CustomControl.

Comment: Do you have some example for your "When you want to implement some additional functionality", because with UserControl also you can add some new functionalities?

Comment: Custom control -  like a datepicker with system masking that supports theme. usercontrol - datepicker with additional buttons.

Answer (score 1):

I think a `UserControl` is the one to choose, for it is used for a kind of "assembly of existing controls". In your case a button and a file open dialog. It will then get a specific look and feel (for example the default look of a button and the default look of a file open dialog).

The `CustomControl` is kind of the other way round. It has no look and feel by itself. It is completely abstract concerning layout. The layout comes into play, wwhen assigning a style to it.

Comment: Yeah but in fact with this control, is not absolutely to arrange the controls, it's more to give a control that could be used to edit a `FilePath`

Comment: @J4N: Of course you can build a `CustomControl` if you like, but building a `UserControl` might suffice and may be easier.

Answer (score 0):

In general a custom control extends an existing control while a user control creates a new control type from a collection of existing controls. I would say that a user control is better suited, based on the information you've given.